# Weak convergence of a sequence of stationary distributions to another stationary distribution

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, weak-convergence

Let $\{X_n(t) \in \mathbb{R}^+\}$ for each $t \in (0,1)$ denote a discrete time Markov chain (with time index $n$ and parameterized by $t$). For each $t$, the Markov chain $\{X_n(t)\}$ has a unique stationary distribution, $X_{\infty}(t) \in \mathbb{R}^+$, i.e.,
$$X_n(t) \rightarrow^w X_{\infty}(t). $$

Suppose for each $n$, $X_n(t)$ converges weakly to $\overline{X}_n$ as $t \rightarrow 0$, i.e., 
$$X_n(t) \rightarrow^w  \overline{X}_n$$

The sequence $\{\overline{X}_n \in \mathbb{R}^+\}$ is also a Markov chain. Suppose it has a unique stationary distribution $\overline{X}_{\infty} \in \mathbb{R}^+$, i.e.,
$$\overline{X}_n \rightarrow^w  \overline{X}_\infty.$$

Are there general conditions under which $X_{\infty}(t)$ converge to $\overline{X}_{\infty}$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$, i.e., 
$$ X_{\infty}(t) \rightarrow^w \overline{X}_{\infty}.$$

I believe that the above problem would require some justification for an exchange of limits. I want to know if under Markovian conditions there are some results which justify these results.

Comment: Why can you be sure that the sequence $\{\overline{X_n}\}$ is a Markov chain with a unique stationary distribution? Is this an assumption in your problem?

Comment: It is an assumption, I have edited the problem.

Comment: What is the state space here?  Finite, countable, general?

Comment: Is the Markov chain time-homogeneous? If yes (and if the state space is finite), then the question would reduce to the question whether the eigenvectors of a matrix are a continuous function of the matrix entries.

Comment: I have indicated the state space for the relevant processes and the limits in the problem.

Comment: @Bernhard The state space is not finite. I would like to know if there is a  reference on how such a thing would work in finite state space, if it is immediate, could you please elaborate.

Comment: @Sudheer: Eigenvectors are continuous w.r.t. the matrix entries (at least if they correspond to simple eigenvalues, as it happens to be the case here). For a time-homogeneous Markov chain on a finite state space, the stationary distribution is the dominant left eigenvector. The dominant left eigenvector is a continuous function of the matrix entries by assumption. If for all $n$, $X_n(t)\to \overline{X}_n$, the corresponding transition matrices also converge (don't they?). The exchange of limit is possible due to continuity. I hope this helps, I could expand in an answer, if necessary.

Comment: @Bernhard Thanks, it will be good if you expand it in the form of an answer. It seems correct to me.

Comment: I used "Principles of Mathematical Analysis -- Rudin, Theorem 7.11" to get this result. Suppose, we have for each $y, \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}(X_n(t) \leq y) = \mathbb{P}(X_\infty(t) \leq y) $ uniformly over $t$ and suppose for each $y, \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \mathbb{P}(X_n(t) \leq y) = \mathbb{P}(\overline{X}_n \leq y)$, Then $\mathbb{P}(\overline{X}_n \leq y)$ converges as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and $$ \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}(X_n(t) \leq y) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \mathbb{P}(X_n(t) \leq y)$$.

Comment: @Bernhard: do you have a reference for eigenvectors being continuous w.r.t. the matrix entries.

Comment: @Sudheer: Yes, I found one. Chapter 9.1 in "Matrix Theory and Applications with MATLAB" by Hartfiel should give you some information about that.